# How can I remotely change the volume?

Tags: audio, ssh, remote-control, command-line

At home I often connect my android to some speakers, to listen to internet-radio. It would like to be able to change the sound-level through a command on my laptop.

I can open an ssh shell to the phone, but I am stuck finding a command to change the volume on the android.

Is there a command to change the audio-volume on the android-shell? Or maybe there is a different approach without ssh that I missed completely?

I am running Android 4.1.

**Edit**

The accepted answer should work for rooted devices. I am still keen on getting an answer for an unrooted device.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [simulating keyevents on Android](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.de/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html) and search for "KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP" and "KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN".

Events can be generated by executing "input":

```
#local shell:
input keyevent 24 #vol up
input keyevent 25 #vol down
#remotely using ssh
ssh your-phone input keyevent 24 #vol up
ssh your-phone input keyevent 25 #vol down

# 'su -c command' to make it run as root (if not already). EDIT: now escaped properly.
ssh your-phone su -c "input\ keyevent\ 24" #vol up
ssh your-phone su -c "input\ keyevent\ 25" #vol down"
```

Your shell needs appropriate permissions most probably to fire input events I guess. If you do public key authentication and keep your private key loaded in memory (ssh-add) you can make a wrapper script and just execute this without beeing asked for a passphrase. **Note:** There's a considerable overhead for both 'su' and 'input', all in all one single volume adjust takes 2.5s to complete on my HTC Desire.

EDIT2:

```
shell@android:/ $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),[...]
shell@android:/ $ time input keyevent 24                                       
    0m0.92s real     0m0.29s user     0m0.06s system
```

Seems like you have to be member of the input group (here GID=2004) to have the capability to generate keyevents using 'input'. Also, I noticed that the screen has to not be locked (and/or off), because the lock would consume all keyevents eventually. Note also that the command takes almost 1 second.

Comment: This looks very promising. The commands are accepted by the shell without failure, but the volume does not change. I will probably have to play a bit more with my permissions.

Comment: it works for me (using a locally connected phone via "adb shell" with root). Most probably it's a question of permissions. Maybe look at logcat if there's some output about rejected 'input' calls

Comment: Nope: I don't think I have root access. Additionally, It tells me 'su not found' when running as android user. Logcat gives the following output: `I/Input   ( 2502): InjectKeyEvent: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=399847, downTime=399847, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
I/Input   ( 2502): InjectKeyEvent: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=399847, downTime=399847, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }`. I have to add that I am new to android.

Comment: Ok, I am not a member of the input(1004) group. I will root my device one day, and try again.

Comment: There must be an option to **not** needing root, like (mis)using tasker with intents for that (tasker most likely has the necessary rights for almost everything...)

Comment: tasker works on un-rooted devices only by using an AccessibilityService.. and an AccessibilityService can only interact with default ui-elements like buttons and views - or elements that have explicit made accessible by the app-creator, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#onAccessibilityEvent%28android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent%29